# Abstract Algebra Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't know how to even approach this problem.

Let **G** be the group of rotations of a plane about a point **P** in the plane. Thinking of **G** as a Group of permutations of the plane, describe the orbit of a point **Q** in the plane.

Comment: If you apply the rotations about $P$ to a point $Q$, you get the set of all points obtained by rotating $Q$ around $P$ - i.e. you get the circle around $P$ containing $Q$. This should be  obvious on some level.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since rotations are isometries that preserve distance, each image of Q under this permutation is equidistant from P . Hence, the orbit of Q is a circle with center P and radius d(P, Q).